# Start second program and kill first (cmd.exe) in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, pid, taskkill

There is running .exe program (cmd.exe in task manager).
I need to start the second instance of the program and after 10 seconds kill the first instance. `PID` changes every time a new instance is started.
Is it possible **with one BAT file** to start second instance, wait 10 seconds and kill first instance?

Comment: Get the PID from `tasklist`, start the new instance, `taskkill` the old PID.